# Why can't I send email using Perl CGI script on CentOS?

Tags: perl, email, cgi, centos

I'm using this [CGI script](http://www.kent-web.com/cgi/down.cgi?name=PostMail&file=zip).

CGI is working, but I cannot sent emails from this form in CentOS. Please help me? Do I have to set-up anything for it? or MTA?

Comment: It would help to post the relevant bit of the code right here.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, kind of hard to check. It appears fairly generously commented, unfortunately in Japanese :-/.

From what I can see, it expects you to set variable $server to be a SMTP server that accepts outgoing mail. So you'll need (access to) an SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

You should check sendmail command

```
$ which sendmail
$ ls /usr/bin/sendmail
```

and, can you send email with sendmail command?

Answer (score 1):

Perl comes with excellent documentation that is accessible from the command line using `perldoc` on your computer. To get help on `perldoc`:

```
$ perldoc perldoc
```

Table of contents

```
$ perldoc perltoc
```

Help on a function

```
$ perldoc -f open
```

Search FAQ list for a keyword:

```
$ perldoc -q mail
$ perldoc -q "How do I send mail"
```

Depending on the OS/distribution combination, an HTML version of the documentation might also be installed. You should skim through the FAQ and the main parts at least once a year, every year.

I do not think it is a good idea for us to download some arbitrary binary posted somewhere. If you are going to post code, post it here. As for your question, the FAQ might help you begin to debug: [How do I send mail?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq9.html#How-do-I-send-mail%3f)